# alternatives config does not change java version in CentOS

Tags: java, linux, centos6

I am installing Jdk 1.8 in centos 6.4 machine.

java -version

> java version "1.7.0_67"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (busudo yum install dsc21-2.1.13-1 cassandra2.1.6-1
>   [image]ild 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

I downloaded jdk 1.8 from Oracle website and installed it.

> alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java 2

once it is installed, I used

> alternatives --config java

to set the current java version to 1.8.

- There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

### Selection    Command

- 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
  2           /opt/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java
- 3           /opt/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java

I picked the 3rd option after which java -version does not change anything. Its still showing the same old 1.7 version. I tried appending newly installed java directory to the PATH variables and then changed JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME to point newly installed java directories both of which did not yield any outcome.

Just wondering if I am missing any step here.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try `sudo alternatives --config java` ?

Comment: tried that..no luck!!

Comment: Can you post your PATH value and output of `ls -lrt \`which java\``

Comment: ls -lrth which java > -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7718 Sep  2  2014 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java

Comment: Note that I am working on cloudera VM. echo $PATH: [root@quickstart jdk1.8.0_91]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/firefox:/sbin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin:/usr/local/apache-ant/apache-ant-1.9.2/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin:

Comment: I have actually made quite a few changes in .bash_profile to have JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME set to my new installation dir. echo $JAVA_HOME would point to JDK 1.8 but the output of echo $PATH left me wondering how the old java installation path is stillshowing up in PATH. Any chance it could be coming from settings in a different user. I did all these changes as root but if default settings from other users are still reflecting in here..

Comment: Encountered same error any work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think, `java version "1.7.0_67" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01) Java` is /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera/bin/java.
So, try removing this from your PATH and run `alternatives` commands again.

Comment: I actually did that. Glimpse of my .bash_profile: #JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera
#export JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_91
export JAVA_HOME
JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_91/jre

Comment: I just wanted to show that I have JAVA_HOME set to new Java installation folder

Comment: JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME environment variables are used by applications to determine which java executable to use. But if you want to set a particular version of java, I think, you should remove the old java versions from your PATH and have the newer version of java in it.

Comment: I am confused at the same point..I commented out the jdk 1.7 from PATH in my .bash_profile from the root but it still shows up in PATH even after sourcing new bash_profile. Any help in identifying where else I need to make changes to get jdk 1.7 out of path

Comment: You may need to check .bashrc and would you mind attaching your .bash_profile?

Comment: Just added sc shots of the bash_profile, one from cloudera and other from root

Comment: Did you run `source ~/.bashrc` after making the changes? or else, check the $PATH in a new terminal.